# how to close modal popup on click on submit_tag in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to close the popup on the on the click of submit_tag button of form.

On the click of submit tag it does everything correctly except it does not close the popup. how can I close this popup?

here is the below code:

```
<%= submit_tag 'run_controller',
    {:class=>'btn btn-primary',:id=>'execute',:onclick => 'save_info()'} %>
```

Comment: Which plugin you are using for modal popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# app/assets/javascripts/hide_modal.js.coffee

$ ->
  $('#execute').on "click", -> 
    $('#myModal').modal('hide')
```

or

```
$ ->
  $('form#the_form').on "submit", -> 
    $('#myModal').modal('hide')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap modal pop up then use this.

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

If you are using any specific plug-in then check their documentation to close it.

Comment: I used this line of code but it is not closing. what iam trying to do do is perform two things, one is to call the action in controller and second is to call javascript function to save some data.